# QT SqlQueryModel TableView to ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I need some help. I managed to show my data from database with a tableview. The question is this. How can I switch from tableview to listview.
This is my SqlQueryModel.h code.

```
#ifndef SQLQUERYMODEL_H
#define SQLQUERYMODEL_H
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlQueryModel>
#include <QSqlRecord>

class SqlQueryModel : public QSqlQueryModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString query READ queryStr WRITE setQueryStr NOTIFY queryStrChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList userRoleNames READ userRoleNames CONSTANT)
public:
    using QSqlQueryModel::QSqlQueryModel;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const
    {
       QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
       for (int i = 0; i < record().count(); i ++) {
           roles.insert(Qt::UserRole + i + 1, record().fieldName(i).toUtf8());
       }
       return roles;
   }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    {
        QVariant value;
        if (index.isValid()) {
            if (role < Qt::UserRole) {
                value = QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
            } else {
                int columnIdx = role - Qt::UserRole - 1;
                QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), columnIdx);
                value = QSqlQueryModel::data(modelIndex, Qt::DisplayRole);
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
    QString queryStr() const{
        return query().lastQuery();
    }
    void setQueryStr(const QString &query){
        if(queryStr() == query)
            return;
        setQuery(query);
        emit queryStrChanged();
    }
    QStringList userRoleNames() const {
        QStringList names;
        for (int i = 0; i < record().count(); i ++) {
            names << record().fieldName(i).toUtf8();
        }
        return names;
    }
signals:
    void queryStrChanged();
};
#endif // SQLQUERYMODEL_H
```

This is my main.cpp code.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QtSql/QSqlError>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlQueryModel>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QDebug>
#include "SqlQueryModel.h"

static bool createConnection()
{

        QSqlDatabase db =  QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
                     db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
                     db.setUserName("bogdan");
                     db.setPassword("12345");
                     db.setDatabaseName("aplicatie");

                        db.open();
         QSqlQuery query;

    query.exec("SELECT id_oras ,nume FROM orase");

        if(!query.exec()){
            qDebug()<<query.lastError().text();
            return false;
        }

    return true;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qmlRegisterType<SqlQueryModel>("Foo", 1, 0, "SqlQueryModel");
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    if(!createConnection())
        return -1;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

This is my main.qml code.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
//import QtQuick.Controls 2.13
import Foo 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("SqlQueryModel")
   SqlQueryModel {
        id: sqlmodel
        query: "SELECT id_oras ID,nume FROM orase"
    }
    Component{
        id: columnComponent
        TableViewColumn {width: 100 }
    }
    TableView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        resources:{
            var roleList = sqlmodel.userRoleNames
            var temp = []
            for(var i in roleList){
                var role  = roleList[i]
                temp.push(columnComponent.createObject(view, { "role": role, "title": role}))
            }
            return temp
        }
        model: sqlmodel
    }
}
```

The output is this ->

[image] and I want to switch to Listview like this

[image]

Thank you in advance and Happy new Year!!

Comment: use `ListView{
    model: sqlmodel
    anchors.fill: parent
    delegate: Text{
        anchors.fill: parent
        text: model.ID + " " + model.nume
    }
}`

Comment: Your answer from the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021702/qsqlquerymodel-reference-error-in-rolename-for-listview-qml doesn't help me that's why I post another question.

Comment: To say that it does not help does not help us to know that it is failing so you must give more detail. Have you used the code I have provided? You must remove the part of the TableView and place the ListView code from my previous comment

Comment: I wrote to you in chat to avoid spamming here

Comment: oops: change to `ListView{ model: sqlmodel anchors.fill: parent delegate: Text{ text: model.ID + " " + model.nume } }`